# XMPP Chat plugin for Magento

Tags: magento, plugins, xmpp, chat, openfire

I've Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 community edition and [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) ([Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) 3.6.4) installed on a Ubuntu server.

Is there any plugins like [Zopim Live Chat](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zopim-live-chat.html) or [YALC](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/yalc-yet-another-live-chat.html) that can be configured to work with my own XMPP server?